# E-mail Operator only on Maintenance Plan Failure

Tags: sql-server, email, maintenance-plan

I know you can use Reporting and Logging wizard to setup a report e-mail for a maintenance plan, but is there a way to only send this out if there was a failure? I'm interested in receiving emails on errors for Back Up Database and Check Database Integrity Tasks in a maintenance plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

right-click the sql agent job, click properties, go to notifications.  Set up an operator witht he appropriate email and then select email, select the operator, and then when the job fails.  click ok and you should be good to go.  note that this solution will only take care of one sql server agent job (each sub plan for a maintenance plan).  so you'll have to set up the notification on each part of the subplan (if you have multiple subplans).

[How to create an operator.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175962.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup a notification for a single step in a subplan this is what you do: On the Check Database Integrity Task in the maintenance plan attach the green line to a new Notify Operator Task setup the way you want it.  Right-click the green line and change it from Success to Failure.  From my testing you cannot right-click the green line until it is attached.